# Block classes are missing from markup. How do I use a block class using the Context module?

Tags: blocks

I am trying to place blocks using context in Drupal 8 and using The *Block class* module to give classes to blocks. The Placement/position of blocks is working fine, but block classes are not appearing in the markup. If I don't use context module then block classes are appearing in markup and working fine.

I am using following:

1. Drupal 8.2.2
2. Block Class 8.x-1.x-dev
3. Context 8.x-1.0-alpha1+2-dev